# Using RestAssured, I am getting a partial response. not sure what exactly am I missing

Tags: post, rest-assured

Request being sent:
'''@Test
public void firstPost() {
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in/";

```
    JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject();
     reqBody.put("name", "Ajay");
     reqBody.put("job", "leader");
    
    RequestSpecification reqSpec = RestAssured.given()
            .body(reqBody);
    Response res = reqSpec.post("/api/users");
    
    System.out.println(res.asString());
    
}'''
```

Response being printed is:
{"id":"403","createdAt":"2020-08-28T18:13:32.294Z"}

Expected response
{
"name": "Ajay",
"job": "leader",
"id": "403",
"createdAt": "2020-08-28T18:13:32.294Z"
}

Comment: This is a post request, After given add `contentType("application/json")`

Answer (score 0):

You should add contentType like below.

```java
@Test
public void firstPost() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in/";

    JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject();
    reqBody.put("name", "Ajay");
    reqBody.put("job", "leader");
    
    RequestSpecification reqSpec = RestAssured.given()
            .contentType("application/json") // <-- add this
            .body(reqBody);
    Response res = reqSpec.post("/api/users");
    
    System.out.println(res.asString());
    
}
```

See the [official wiki](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#content-type) for more info about **Content Type**

Comment: Hi, @Test-Again , if this is the solution to your problem, please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)